# JWPlayer and IE11 -- Could not add internal listener

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

The player works fine on all other browsers, but isn't working in IE11. I'm getting the error message "Could not add internal listener" 8 times (one time for each playlist item, I assume).

The script gets to the onReady event, but never gets to onPlay. I'm running version 6.8. I have confirmed that the playList is being generated as it should, and as I mentioned, it works in all browsers except for IE11.

```
//get our playlist
var playListItems = [];
$(courseXML).find("audiofile").each(function() {
    var newItem = {
        file: "assets/audio/"+ $(this).text(),
    type: "mp3"
        };
        playListItems.push(newItem);
});

//redoing this as a playlist
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        flashplayer: "js/jwplayer.flash.swf",
        html5player: "js/jwplayer.html5.js",
        controls: false,
        width: 1,
        height: 1,
        autostart: false,
        playlist: playListItems,
        allowscriptaccess: 'always',
        events: {
            onComplete: function() {
        alert("I'm completed");
            },
            onReady: function() {
                alert("I'm ready");

            },
            onPlay: function() { 
                alert("I'm playing!");

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: do you have current MIME-TYPE ?